# Is there anyway I can insert an SQL statement on the click of a button

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table set up as seen below:

[image: Table Setup]

I have a slideshow (slides are on different .php pages) and at the bottom of each page I have a button, they click on which just holds the `a href` to the next or on the back button, previous page.

I need to store which number slide they are on into the `userTakingModule` table in the `checkPoint`. Is there anyway someone could give me some guidance on how to do this please. The first slide they reach I guess it would be an INSERT query, then if there is already a value held in `checkPoint` it would be an UPDATE query. I'm so lost, anyone able to shed some much needed light?

The button code at the end of each slide:

```
<div class="arrow-container">
  <button><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></a></button><button><a href="slide2.php"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a></button>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, `a` inside `button` is invalid HTML to begin with already. And then, you need to be a bit more specific as to what you are actually struggling with - see [ask] for starters, please.

Comment: Hi @04FS I see what would be the best way then to skip to another page with using a link (if not a button) and also being able to store a value in it (for my PHP) ?

Comment: Query string / GET parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution for this is, 
**If** there is entry into table regarding checkpoint then update that entry with new data **else** insert new entry. You can insert and update with same query by using

> INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ((which will execute the UPDATE at the end if name already exists [see documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html))

Comment: Hi @sarfaraz thank you, so this essentially says insert first (however IF there is a value already there), then update instead?